# google cloud storage not posting back to my upload handler

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, dropzone.js

as stated in here https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsmanager , using php for google app engine. Google cloud storage API will send you your upload handler a notification when uploads are made however this isnt the case for me.

I use dropzone javascript library to upload to google cloud storage, it works fine, my files are uploaded however, the cloud storage doesnt notify back my "uploadhandler.php" which needs to move the temporary file to the final target. here is the code :

uploadhandler.php :

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //3             

array_push($_SESSION["property"] - > images, $tempFile);

$name = GenerateName(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$targetFile = "gs://mapestate/uploads/images/".$name; //5

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile); //6

$_SESSION["property"] - > status = 3;
```

My upload function that succesfully uploads to cloud storage :

```
$options = ['gs_bucket_name' = > 'uploads/images/'];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('uploadhandler.php', $options); ?>
< div id = "images" > 
< form action = "<?php echo $upload_url ?>" class = "dropzone" id = "demo-upload" > 
< /form>
</div >
```

Comment: Have you configured notifications for that bucket? Have you configured your application handler to respond to the appropriate URL in app.yaml? For more details on notifications, check out https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I thought it was done automatically, thats what they at least said in the documentation in the thread, they never said anything about allowing notifications, and I could see this needed authentications of Oauth, while app engine and google cloud they have app authentication. I dont really get it how its done for applications in that documentation :/

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me which thread you're talking about? I'm afraid I must be missing some context.

Comment: Could you share your app.yaml?